# Date format change in java

Tags: java, date

Hi I've seen there are a lot of questions about this but I didn't see any that ask what happends if I'm getting a string like this "01-Nov-2012" and I need to transform it to "mm/dd/yyyy" how can I do that? is a problem the string I'm getting? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Us a SimpleDateFormatter to parse the String '01-Nov-2012' than use anothe SimpleDateFormatter to create the new String '11/01/2012'

Comment: I'm extracting that date data directly from PDF's and to get the precise values I need, I use Regexps so the data it returns to me is in the format I posted, but as i'm getting the information in Strings I needed to ask.

Comment: @MrSmith42 One to get the info I have and one to print it in the new format?

Answer (score 2):

You can use two [SimpleDateFormats](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) - one to parse the input and one to produce the output:

```
String input =  "01-Nov-2012";
Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.US).parse(input);
String output = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(d);
System.out.println("output = " + output); //prints 11/01/2012
```

Note: it is good practice to specify the locale when the date includes words ("Nov") to make sure the proper language is used.

Comment: Thank you that's all I needed to know!! The thing about the "nov" month display. THANK YOU @assylias !!